# My SQLite breaks my app, it says that there is no column called Goal

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to store a set of string variables into an SQLite database, it worked until I added two more columns called "Weight" and "Goal". Unfortunately, whenever I try to compile it now it stops working, stating that

```
04-21 20:19:11.675    2000-2000/com.example.wolfe_000.final_final_zeno E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table Registered_Info has no column named Goal
```

As I said before it worked before I added weight and goal, here is the code for the database operations:

public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static int database_version = 1;
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "+TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + "("+TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME+" TEXT,"+TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS+" TEXT,"+TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL+" TEXT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_WEIGHT+" TEXT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_GOAL+" TEXT );";


public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
    super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "Database Created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "Table Created");
    sdb.close();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

}

public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name, String pass, String email, String weight, String goal) {
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, pass);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_WEIGHT,weight);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_GOAL,goal);
    long k = SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "One Row Inserted");
    SQ.close();
}

public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop){
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, TableData.TableInfo.USER_WEIGHT, TableData.TableInfo.USER_GOAL};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    return CR;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change database_version = 2; or delete app from device.

then try

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(NkSQLiteOpenHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: Tried that already, doesn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: @JamesWolfe Have you tried both, or just increasing the version number?

Comment: I'm using an emulator, I closed that emulator, opened a new, different emulator and it still doesn't work.

Comment: implement  onUpgrade

Comment: He means uninstall the app from whatever system it is currently installed. So if an emulator, start the emulator, uninstall the app from within the emulator, reinstall (or Run from your editor, which will install automatically).